# Why do I get a stack overflow exception when compiling?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, new-operator

Inside my main function I create a 2D array

```
int (*Matrix)[100] = new int[200][100];
```

This works, but if I double the number of rows and columns I get a stack overflow error.
I thought new doesn't put the variables on the stack, am I wrong ?

Comment: What language and compiler?

Comment: The left hand side kinda looks like a function pointer.

Comment: Sorry I've edited the tags. It does look like, but it is not because there is no parameters.

Comment: That should not be the cause of a stack overflow. It requires a single pointer in the stack, and even if it needed more than that, 400*200*4  = 320.000 or approx. 300kb, which is hardly a size that should trigger a stack overflow (unless you are in some constrained environment).

Comment: You get an error when "compiling" or when you run the program?  I tested your line of code with all bounds set to 5000 and had no trouble.  You should post a short complete compilable example.